# What is the best approach to scoping and evaluating the feasibility of bringing a library like Kimera Semantics to mobile?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, ros, semantic-segmentation

A few months ago, a library, Kimera Semantics was released by MIT-SPARK (https://github.com/MIT-SPARK/Kimera-Semantics). This technology has broad implications if it could be brought to mobile in an open source way.

Kimera depends on ROS, and ROS supports both iOS and Android devices, but I am not sure how to connect the dots between the mobile versions of ROS and a library such as this.

Is there a recommended approach to use when scoping the challenges or feasibility of such an effort?